# How to preserve tabs in semiverbatim?

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I have the following slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\Proc}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\Var}[1]{\ensuremath{\textcolor{varcolor}{#1}}}

\newcommand{\Com}[1]{\textcolor{comcolor}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Blue}[1]{\textcolor{varcolor}{#1}}
\definecolor{varcolor}{RGB}{15,122,183}

\definecolor{comcolor}{RGB}{10,161,119}
\definecolor{framecolour}{HTML}{009980}

\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Finding the majority}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[text width=5.5cm]
\begin{semiverbatim}
\Proc{Majority}(\Blue{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n})

\Com{initialise} item \Var{m}
\Com{initialise} counter \Var{c=0} 
for each item \Var{x_i} in sequence 
    if \Var{x_i} == \Var{m}
        \Var{c} = \Var{c} + 1   
    else 
        if \Var{c} == 0
            \Var{m} = \Var{x_i}
            \Var{c} = \Var{c} + 1
        else
            \Var{c} = \Var{c} - 1
\end{semiverbatim}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately none of the indentation in the `semiverbatim` part is shown.

[image]

Why is this?

As a secondary question, is there way to get the subscripts in `x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n` to work?

## EDIT

It seems the problem only appears if I use tabs. If you replace them with spaces it works fine.  If you copy and paste the LaTeX from this question it seems you will get spaces so you will need to convert them back to tabs to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the *"semiverbatim indentation"*?

Comment: @AndreC The OP just means indentation in the semiverbatim environment. As in the first if statement.

Comment: @Anush Okay, and what does he think is wrong?

Comment: @AndreC The lack of indentation it seems.  The whitespaces  should be giving indentation.

Comment: @Anush It seems to me that the spaces are perfectly preserved. As far as I'm concerned, I don't see any problem here.

Comment: @AndréC I added a picture. Does it not look like that for you?

Comment: @fomin No, for me, the indentation is perfectly preserved. What is your compilation engine? pdfLaTeX? LuaLaTeX ? another one ?

Comment: @AndréC pdflatex. Are you using tabs or spaces? If I replace the tabs with spaces it all works I just discovered.

Comment: @fomin I just copied and pasted your code as is, and after checking, it put spaces everywhere.

Comment: @AndréC That explains it.  What happens if you replace the spaces with tabs?

Comment: @fomin This removes the indentation. Change your title by requesting that the tabs be kept.

Comment: @fomin What is the language used in the code? C language?

Comment: @AndréC It's just pseudocode